# Style isolation in microfrontend architecture

Tags: javascript, vue.js, shadow-dom, micro-frontend

I have a case. I need to integrate one Vue js application into another using the Webpack Module Federation plugin. Using the configs, I was able to distribute the component to another application (layout). However, I'm having a problem with my app's styles overriding the app's layout styles. I use bootstrap as global styles. It contains styles for tags that break layout styles. If I use shdow root, I have to make quite a lot of changes to the code, at least manually encapsulating the styles. Secondly, the styles I encapsulate in shdow root contain :root selectors, which do not apply to shadow root styles. Is it possible to solve the styling problem with a simple, elegant solution?

Comment: "styles I encapsulate in shdow root contain :root selectors" - probably needs to be processed with style processor, so there would be :host counterpart. Generally needs to be `$root: string.unquote(':root') !default; #{$root} { ... }` to be more flexible. Generally prefixing selectors can give you a namespace, e.g. in sass can be achieved by importing all global styles inside a selector, `.my-app { @import "...." }` or `.my-app { @include meta.load-css("....") }`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The solution of adding a prefix with postcss-prefix-selector module helped me to solve this problem:)

Answer (score 0):

The solution of adding a prefix with postcss-prefix-selector module helped me to solve this problem:)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-prefix-selector